# Laravel Auth::check()

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am working on a project of laravel.I have a table name user type.I have two types of users 'common' and 'admin' which i set id respectively 1 and 2.And I am giving 2 types of nav bars in header for different users.The common is for all users and admin is for signed up users.But to give a admin nav to a signed up user every time i have to set the user_type_id to 2 manually going to my database.But i want to do it dynamically like,if(Auth::check()){user_type_id=2}.How can I do that?

this is my header code if you need to see:

```
<p style="display:none;">
            @if(Auth::check())

                {{ $a = 'includes.navs.'.Auth::user()->userType->name }}
            @else

               {{ $a = "includes.navs.common" }} 


            @endif
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- Normal users are stored with a `user_type_id` of 1
- Admin users are stored with a `user_type_id` of 2

Given that you could just do this:

```
<p style="display:none;">
    @if(Auth::check())
        @if(Auth::user()->user_type_id == 2)
        {{ $a = 'includes.navs.'.Auth::user()->userType->name }}
        @endif
    @else
    {{ $a = "includes.navs.common" }} 
    @endif
</p>
```